# Transposing a graph(2D Array) where the graph[i].length = degree of i

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, graph, transpose

I have to transpose a graph, that is implemented as a 2D array (with variable sizes of the 2nd dimension for every element in the first dimension). A graph in my code looks like this:

```
new GraphImpl(new int [] [] {
    {1,3,4,5},      //this is knot 0, which has a edge to 1, 3, 4, 5
    {5,3},          //this is knot 1, which has a edge to 5, 3
    {},             //this is knot 2, which has no edges
    {5},
    {1,5},
    {},
    {5},
    {1,4,5,6}
})
```

The problem: How do i get the size of the 2nd dimension of the array for the transposed graph right?

Transposed Graph should look like this:

```
{},
{0,4,7},
{},
{0,1},
{0,7},
{0,1,3,4,6,7},
{7},
{}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: well, nothing really yet, since i dont know where to start... I already "transposed" the graph with a binomial heap (i put the the index of the neighbours as the priority and the knot source as data, so when i call the extract minimum function of the binomial heap class(code doesn't really matter at this point) i get all knots, with their neighbours in ascending order.) However, i dont know, how to initialize the array for the transposed graph, since i don't know how to implement variable sizes of the second dimension of the array for each element in the first dimension of the array.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For example to iterate twice to get the connected nodes for an array. Once just for counting and getting the array dimension an the second time to get the nodes. Or you use a ```List``` instead of an array and then convert it to an array, when completely filled.

Comment: I'd rather not use ArrayList since i'd have to impot it from java.util and i don't know if i'm allowed to do that.
I thought about the double iteration, but i have no idea how that should work. Can i iterate and do g[i] = new int[neighbours] ?!

Comment: I tried it, and it works just like that, thank you very much

Comment: Would yo u please upvote my comment then?